# Simulating static web request through Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, scheduling, load-testing

I am doing simulation of web request executing on a web server.Web server is simulated through a simple Thread Pool object accepting request from a queue
and run by Workers. Since web request may be static(I/O bound) or dynamic(CPU-Bound) so i simulated web requests as CpuBoundJob and IoBoundJob that are Runnable objects as in the following code.The sleep time in sleep method specifies amount of time a static web page takes to read from the disk and send to web client. The problem is Thread.sleep() in case of IoBoundJob, which is not precise and same IoBoundJob can have different response times on different runs. That is a same static request may take different response times by different web clients(response time is not 100% accurate for static request). No doubt that
Thread.sleep() is not precise and can sleep more than specified but i think this is the beauty of Thread.sleep() when it is used for simulating any IO bound job(static web request) because in case of IoBound job when an Io completes it is not necessary that it immediately grab the processor and finish its run, instead when its I/O completes it may take a little to wait for the processor which is busy in other jobs.

---

Is my perception right or not ? If it is not right then what is the precise alternative of Thread.sleep() in my simulation project scenario? I cant swap Thread.sleep() with spin as spin is used in case of CPU-Bound job as i have used in the following code.

```
public class CpuBoundJob  Runnable {
    long delay;
         public CpuBoundJob(long delay) {
            this.dlay=delay;
              }
        @Override
        public void run() {

             long timeToWait = this.delay;
             long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
             while(startTime + timeToWait > System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    }
```

---

```
 public class IoBoundJob  implements Runnable {
    long delay;
 public IoBoundJob(long delay) {
    this.dlay=delay;
  }
  @Override
public void run() {

    try{

Thread.currentThread().sleep(this.delay);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){ }
   }
}
```

Comment: You say that dynamic requests are CPU-bound, but in reality, they are much more likely to be Database-bound, or potentially Web-Service-bound. Also IO-bound is not a true check, because static resources are very likely to be in disk-cache, so they are not really IO-bound most of the time.

Comment: Your conceptions of "static" vs "dynamic" are misled here. The difference here lies between whether an execution path can be preempted or not.

Comment: What is it you are truly simulating here? How a client sees a server under load? How many simulated requests a server can handle per minute before performance degrades? Something else?

Comment: @fge Combining our two comments, it means that IO-bound, Database-bound, and Web-Service-bound, all means that the request processing is waiting on an external resource, which means they yield the CPU to process other requests, without the need for the CPU to preempt them, which is otherwise needed for purely CPU-bound tasks. Depending on web server, there may of course be CPU-bound processing, but your simulation seems overly simplified.

Comment: I am working on thread pool tuning strategies that may be used in web servers application servers file servers as a Thread pool.

Comment: I am sending Runnable objects through sockets which are then executed by workers on thread pool and when a task is completed it is send bak to my client software which plots the response times of task Each Runnable object.Each RunnableObject extends ParentJob that provides methods for time stamping so each task records it waiting time in the queue and total execution time.

Comment: My client is able to send request to the thread pool at any frequeny and by any distribution e.g. Poisson ,Guassian.

Comment: Just a question... Why don't you just rely on the underlying OS scheduling?

Comment: Requests on apllcation and web servers are not scheduled by OS but by Thread Pools embedded in servers and i am working on performance measurement of scheduling policy of thread pools. u came to the point urself Thanks god!

Comment: Andreas plz tell me just 1 thing that is it possible that a static http request of a web page may have different response times on dieeferent runs at load testing?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah an HTTP request for a static resource can vary in service time substantially depending on warmness of web tier caches, file system caches, and even processor caches. Latency of web requests can be influenced by "network weather" effects like congestion.  It's fine to simulate fixed delays, but recognize that as a control point in your study that will fluctuate in practice.

Comment: Dear Alain ! It means that Thread.sleep() is suitable to simulates an http request because both may run on the server more than expected service time . Is not it?

Comment: Alian also i could not understand your last sentence!